# Combine sed truncate x lines into a find command

Tags: sed, find

We have a large log file in the same location on multiple servers and I want to create a cron job to truncate the file to last 100k lines.

The following command works:

```
sed -i 1,$(($(wc -l < /root/server123.example.com.log) -100000))d /root/server123.example.com.log
```

But the hostname on each server is different (server1, server2, server3 etc.), and I'd like to have a single command I can paste into each cron file. During my testing I wasn't sure how to achieve a wildcard in the above command.

I think the best way might be to combine it with a find command, but I'm clueless on how to do that..

```
find /root/server*.example.com.log -type f -exec sed <NOT SURE..> \;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: use [logrotate](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) for that. Besides that, the question is off-topic on SO because it is not about programming. superuser.com would be a better fit. But always make sure that you don't ask something that hasn't be answered before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> During my testing I wasn't sure how to achieve a wildcard in the above command.

If there is just one log file on each server, you can simply insert the wildcard:

```
sed -i 1,$(($(wc -l < /root/server*.example.com.log) -100000))d /root/server*.example.com.log
```